# _no_unused_value_warning_ `with sexp` in utop

Tags: ocaml, utop

I added `require "sexplib.syntax";;` and `core` etc in utop.

If I type

```
module type Printer = sig 
  type t with sexp
end
```

in utop, it says

> module type Printer = sig type t val t_of_sexp : Sexp.t -> t val
>   sexp_of_t : t -> Sexp.t end

ok, this is no problem.

But if I save the above code into a `ml` file and use it in utop, it gives error:

> Error: Unbound type constructor _no_unused_value_warning_

**Why?** Is this a bug in utop? How can I report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also representable on my system, with

```
Core 111.11.01
Utop 1.12
```

It is a bug, for sure. You should report it to [Jérémie Dimino](https://github.com/diml/utop/issues), as he is responsible for both core and utop.